# airflow command error: argument GROUP_OR_COMMAND: celery subcommand works only with CeleryExecutor

Tags: airflow

I am trying to setup airflow cluster for my project and I am using celery executor as the executor. Along with this I am using Rabbitmq as queueing service, postgresql as database. For now I have two master nodes and two worker nodes. All the services are up and running, I was able to configure my master nodes with airflow webserver and scheduler. But for my worker nodes, I am running into an issue where I get an error:

> airflow command error: argument GROUP_OR_COMMAND: celery subcommand works only with CeleryExecutor, CeleryKubernetesExecutor and executors derived from them, your current executor: SequentialExecutor, subclassed from: BaseExecutor, see help above.

I did configured my airflow.cfg properly. I did set executor value to CeleryExecutor (Doesn't this mean I have set the executor value).

My airflow.cfg is as follows:
Note: I am just adding parts of the config that I think is relevant to the issue.

```
[celery]

# This section only applies if you are using the CeleryExecutor in
# ``[core]`` section above
# The app name that will be used by celery
celery_app_name = airflow.executors.celery_executor

# The concurrency that will be used when starting workers with the
# ``airflow celery worker`` command. This defines the number of task instances that
# a worker will take, so size up your workers based on the resources on
# your worker box and the nature of your tasks
worker_concurrency = 16

# The maximum and minimum concurrency that will be used when starting workers with the
# ``airflow celery worker`` command (always keep minimum processes, but grow
# to maximum if necessary). Note the value should be max_concurrency,min_concurrency
# Pick these numbers based on resources on worker box and the nature of the task.
# If autoscale option is available, worker_concurrency will be ignored.
# http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.bin.worker.html#cmdoption-celery-worker-autoscale
# Example: worker_autoscale = 16,12
# worker_autoscale =

# Used to increase the number of tasks that a worker prefetches which can improve performance.
# The number of processes multiplied by worker_prefetch_multiplier is the number of tasks
# that are prefetched by a worker. A value greater than 1 can result in tasks being unnecessarily
# blocked if there are multiple workers and one worker prefetches tasks that sit behind long
# running tasks while another worker has unutilized processes that are unable to process the already
# claimed blocked tasks.
# https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/optimizing.html#prefetch-limits
worker_prefetch_multiplier = 1

# Specify if remote control of the workers is enabled.
# When using Amazon SQS as the broker, Celery creates lots of ``.*reply-celery-pidbox`` queues. You can
# prevent this by setting this to false. However, with this disabled Flower won't work.
worker_enable_remote_control = true

# Umask that will be used when starting workers with the ``airflow celery worker``
# in daemon mode. This control the file-creation mode mask which determines the initial
# value of file permission bits for newly created files.
worker_umask = 0o077

# The Celery broker URL. Celery supports RabbitMQ, Redis and experimentally
# a sqlalchemy database. Refer to the Celery documentation for more information.
broker_url = amqp://admin:password@{hostname}:5672/

# The Celery result_backend. When a job finishes, it needs to update the
# metadata of the job. Therefore it will post a message on a message bus,
# or insert it into a database (depending of the backend)
# This status is used by the scheduler to update the state of the task
# The use of a database is highly recommended
# http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#task-result-backend-settings
result_backend = db+postgresql://postgres:airflow@postgres/airflow
```

```
# The executor class that airflow should use. Choices include
# ``SequentialExecutor``, ``LocalExecutor``, ``CeleryExecutor``, ``DaskExecutor``,
# ``KubernetesExecutor``, ``CeleryKubernetesExecutor`` or the
# full import path to the class when using a custom executor.
executor = CeleryExecutor
```

Please let me know if I haven't added sufficient information pertinent to my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the above error could be:-

Airflow is picking the default value of the executor which is in the core section of airflow.cfg (i.e SequentialExecutor). [This is the template for Airflow's default configuration. When Airflow is imported, it looks for a configuration file at $AIRFLOW_HOME/airflow.cfg. If it doesn't exist, Airflow uses this template](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.2.3/configurations-ref.html#executor).

The following solution is applicable if you are using the [official helm chart](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/helm-chart/stable/index.html):-

1. Change the default value of the executor in the core section of airflow.cfg.
   [Snapshot of default configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1COFy.png)
2. Pass the environment variable called AIRFLOW_HOME in the flower deployment/container. You can simply pass environment variables in all the containers by passing the following in the values file of the helm chart:

```
env:
  - name: "AIRFLOW_HOME"
    value: "/path/to/airflow/home"
```

3. In case the airflow user doesn't have access to the path you passed in the environment variable AIRFLOW_HOME, run the flower container as a root user which can be done by passing the following config in the values file of helm chat.

```
flower:
  enabled: true
  securityContext:
    runAsUser: 0
```